# iOS 6 app hangs on load

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Friday night, my app was working perfectly. So Saturday, I decided to start tweaking the UI. I added an imageview with a background image, pushed it to the back. Then moved some of the controls around to line up better.

Now, my app hangs on the loading screen on the simulator, and goes to a black screen on my iPad. It gives no errors at all.

I did try removing the background image, but that had no effect.

I set breakpoints in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions on the SPRAppDelegate.m and it runs through that function with no problem. Same thing with ViewDidLoad on the SPRViewController.m

I have some subclassed textfields, so I set a breakpoint in one of the awakeFromNib functions in the subclassed file. That doesn't get executed.

I'm not sure what source code would be helpful, but here's my info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>ring-it-up-sm-reversed.png</string>
            <string>ring-it-up-72-reversed.png</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.steveradabaugh.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
</array>
<key>UIStatusBarHidden~ipad</key>
<false/>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I noticed that it doesn't have the main nib listed at all, but I'm thinking that you no longer need to do that.

Here's Main.m
    #import

```
#import "SPRAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([SPRAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

From SPRAppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[SPRViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SPRViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

What else can I put to help?

[EDIT]
I've been playing around trying to figure it out. It shows my loading/splash screen, then shows the background image, but doesn't load any controls on it. (In the simulator). On the device, it shows splash screen, then black. I changed the loading screen so that they would be different from the background.

Comment: How does `SPRViewController.xib` look? Is it by any chance deleted?

Comment: It's there, and looks just fine.

Comment: Okay, I'm stupid.
I set the uicontrol (main container) to have an alpha of 0.
(it was invisible).